# Union and intersection of finite and cofinite sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

With $X$ being the set of all finite or cofinite subsets of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\subseteq$ as a relation.

How do I prove that the union and intersection of some finite subset of $X$, $X_1$, and some cofinite subset of $X$, $X_2$ is, again, in $X$?

I know how to do it when both subsets are either finite or cofinite by using the DeMorgan laws.

But how to do it in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  The intersection of a finite set with anything is finite.  The union of a cofinite set with anything is cofinite.

Comment: I thought the latter was only true for infinite sets. Can you give a hint how to prove the latter please?

Comment: It is the complement of the first.  There are only finitely many things not in the set.  Taking the union can only reduce the set of things not in the set.